# Azure B2C claims transformation, GetClaimFromJson, for standart OpenID Connect provider

Tags: json, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

It looks like claims in Json Object as:

```json
{
  "address": {
    "locality": "Brussels",
    "street_address": "Cookie street 103",
    "postal_code": "1000",
    "formatted": "Cookie street 103 1000 Brussels"
  }
}
```

can not be interpreted well by Azure B2C. However, I struggle with claims transformation instruction to validate in reality. Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimfromjson & https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/tree/main/claims-transformation/json

From github I see they use ExperimentalTechnicalProfile, would it mean it is not applicable for Openid Connect providers? How would you write a claim transformation config within base.xml for example above to parse if Openid Connect should work?

Thanks

I tried multiple configuration, expecting Json object transformed to strings. But instead Azure errors with exception page. Microsoft support can not help themselves for the moment.